# In c++ winrt Navigation view how do I find the nav item that was chosen/clicked?

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

Given a top navigation view in the xaml such as

```xml
<NavigationView  ItemInvoked="NavToAbout" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="nvSample"  PaneDisplayMode="Top">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem IsSelected="True" Content="Main" Tag="Main" />
                <NavigationViewItem   Content="About" Tag="Abouts" />
               <NavigationViewItem   Content="Settings" Tag="Settingspage" />
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
        </NavigationView>
```

And a NavToAbout function like or similar to

```cpp
void  MainPage::NavToAbout(winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationView  const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs const& handler) {


        //Here get value of item
       //auto pageselected = ?
    };
```

How do I find out which page was selected so that I can navigate to the correct page? That is how may I find out which link was clicked?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get which page you choose according to the tag, like `args.InvokedItemContainer().Tag()`. The result is the tag value you set to your item.

```
void  MainPage::NavToAbout(winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationView  const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs const& handler) 
{

    hstring navItemTag = unbox_value<hstring>(handler.InvokedItemContainer().Tag());

};
```